# Spring RestTemplate postForEntity returns Null Objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm new to Spring and I'm having trouble consuming an API and serialising the Response to Java POJOs using Jackson. This the [API](https://www.braze.com/docs/api/endpoints/export/user_data/post_users_identifier/) endpoint I'm trying to consume.

This what my request looks like:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + applicationProperties.getApiKey());

    ArrayList<String> externalIds = new ArrayList<>();
    externalIds.add(userId);

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("external_ids", externalIds);

    HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<>(parameters, headers);

    ResponseEntity<ProfileExportDTO> response = this.restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request , ProfileExportDTO.class);
```

This is my POJO class (setters and getters removed for simplicity):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ProfileExportDTO implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstname;

    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastname;

    private String language;

    private String email;

    private String dob;

    @JsonProperty("home_city")
    private String city;

    private String country;

    private String phone;

    @JsonProperty("time_zone")
    private String timezone;

    @JsonProperty("last_coordinates")
    private float[] lastCoordinates;

    private String gender;

    @JsonProperty("total_revenue")
    private float revenue;

    private String attributed_campaign;

    private String attributed_source;

    private String attributed_adgroup;

    private String push_subscribe;

    private String email_subscribe;
```

My problem is that when this runs the produced object is null. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Does `response.getStatusCodeValue()` return `200` ?

Comment: @出羽和之 returns `201`